Photo Tagging - Best Practices
What is the best tagging approach when you have to tag distinct entities that are identified by the same name?
For instance, if I am tagging pictures of railway stations with hierarchical keywords, I will have something like this:
London
     Cannon Street station

because the station has a unique name.
But in this other case is it better to use this
Witham
     railway station

or this
Witham
     Witham railway station

?
Considering this last example, I suppose that the one of the main differences is that if you use the first tag couple maybe you can do more effective searches for railway stations within your catalogue. While if you use the second example you can search for a certain item (in this case the Withem railway station) without using combinations of tags.

What problem are you trying to solve?

@PhilipKendall, I am trying to understand what can be the best tagging approach before applying it to a massive number of images, if there are already established practices and if there are approaches that are manifestly wrong.

There is no "best"; it depends on what problem you're trying to solve.

@PhilipKendall, thanks for your answer. What I mean is that in the last 2 examples I provided, the 2° (Witham railway station) seems to me to duplicate an information (Witham) that you already had in the previous hierarchical level, but it is more efficient because you can search for just 1 tag and not 2 (Witham + railway station). I wanted to know if there is a general solution that is clearly better than other ones but maybe it is like you say, it only depends by the context and the needs.
